# Kotlin - Secondary constructor that differs by one argument

Tags: kotlin, boilerplate, verbosity

I have a snippet of Kotlin code where the first and the secondary constructor differs minutely, see below

```
class InstructionPrototype constructor(
      val iname: String,
      val opcode: Int,
      val mnemonicExample: String,
      val numericExample: Int,
      val description: String,
      val format: Format,
      val pattern: Pattern,
      var type: Type? = null,
      var rt: Int? = null,
      var funct: Int? = null,
      var conditions: Array<(n: Int) -> String?>? = null) {
  constructor(
        iname: String,
        opcode: Int,
        mnemonicExample: String,
        numericExample: Int,
        description: String,
        format: Format,
        pattern: Pattern,
        type: Type?,
        rt: Int?,
        funct: Int?,
        condition: (n: Int) -> String?
  ): this(iname, opcode, mnemonicExample, numericExample, description, 
        format, pattern, type, rt, funct, arrayOf(condition)) {

  }
```

is it possible to reduce the verbosity of this through some language construct? I was thinking about algebraic data types but that did not feel like a good fit - it came across as "hacky".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Variable number of arguments* (`vararg`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) seems to fit your use case very well, but only if you can abandon `null` as the default value for `conditions` since `vararg` cannot be nullable (e.g. use `emptyArray()`):

```
class InstructionPrototype constructor(
      val iname: String,
      val opcode: Int,
      val mnemonicExample: String,
      val numericExample: Int,
      val description: String,
      val format: Format,
      val pattern: Pattern,
      var type: Type? = null,
      var rt: Int? = null,
      var funct: Int? = null,
      vararg var conditions: (n: Int) -> String? = emptyArray())
```

At use site, you can pass single `(n: Int) -> String?`, and it will be packed into an array, and, in addition to passing several functions separated by comma, you can use the **spread operator** to pass an array:

```
f(vararg a: String) { }

f("a")
f("a", "b", "c")

val array = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
f(*array) // any array of the correct type can be passed as vararg
```

Also, several parameters before `conditions` also have default values, and there's no other way to skip them and pass `conditions` than use [named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments) and the spread operator:

```
fun f(x: Int = 5, vararg s: String) { }

f(5, "a", "b", "c") // correct
f(s = "a") // correct
f(s = "a", "b", "c") // error
f(s = *arrayOf("a", "b", "c") // correct
```